# Unicode Char is not mapped by ObjectMapper correctly for a String property

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, objectmapper

The [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)  converts the following JSON string not right.For some the whole string after  the second unicode char is cut after mapping. \U33a1 represents the m2.

```
text = "Bitte geben Sie Ihre vermietete Fl\U00e4che (\U33a1) an.";


override func mapping(map: Map) {
    super.mapping(map: map)
    hintText = map["hintText"]
    inputType <- (map["inputType"],inputTypeTransformer)
    value <- map["value"]
    capitalizeFirstLetter <- map["capitalizeFirstLetter"]
    maxLength <- map["maxLength"]
    readOnly <- map["readOnly"]
}
```

After mapping hintText gets the value "Vermietete Fläche ("

Apart from this unicode char all the other german accent chars are saved correctly.

Comment: I suspect the problem arises **before** passing the object to the mapper

Comment: Actually the Json dictionary has the correct value

Answer (score 0):

I am not the master of unicodes but seems like swift don't know about this format.

I think, you need to convert them to swift new format. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

```
var text = "Bitte geben \u{24} Sie Ihre vermieteteFl\u{00e4}che (\u{33a1}) an."; // Bitte geben $ Sie Ihre vermieteteFläche (㎡) an.

var string:NSString = "Bitte geben Sie Ihre vermietete Fl\u{00e4}che (\u{33a1}) an."; // Bitte geben Sie Ihre vermieteteFläche (㎡) an.
```